Excel 365 - reorder / sort the Queries & Connections list
I have a very large Excel spreadsheet with over a hundred connections (Data - Queries & Connections).  This list was sorted alphabetically.  I just added another connection, which appeared at the end of the list. I don't see how to put the new item where it belongs in the list.
Web searches come up with a lot of unrelated sorts, as expected.  Excel's own help is useless, or I'm not entering it in a way that it understands what I want (also expected).
